# PHP loop X times based on $interval, but how to handle a rest value?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, for-loop

**[UPDATED with a followup question see edit4]**

So I have a function which returns score average of X number of consecutive dates. But I like to handle the rest value.

For example if I have found the following rows (based on some random data and the hardcoded personid = 133)

[image: based on my random sample data the query returns]

the average output I get when callling the PHP function getConsecutiveInterval(4);

```
Total Found: 10
Num Of Loops: 2.5
2.75
3.5
```

and I expect the averages to be

```
2.75, 3.5 and 3.5(based on the rest 2 dates not 4)
```

And when I use getConsecutiveInterval(3); I expect the average value to be

```
3.33, 3.33, 2.66 and 4 (based on 1 date)
```

and I got

```
Total Found: 10
Num Of Loops: 3.3333333333333
3.3333333333333
3.3333333333333
2.6666666666667
```

So how can I return / handle the rest rows as an average?

This is the php function:

```
function getConsecutiveInterval($interval) {
    //$interval Num Of Consecutive Days
    global $conn;
    $offset = '';
    // Query is the same and at the end of it you include LIMIT to be controlled by the loop.
        $q = "SELECT a.purdate, b.score, a.status FROM records a INNER JOIN scores2 b ON a.purdate = b.date AND a.personid = b.personid WHERE a.personid = 133 AND a.status IN('P','T') ORDER BY purdate ASC, score DESC ";

    //Total Found Use To Divide by
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo 'Total Found: '.$num_rows.'<br/>';
        $numOfLoops = $num_rows/$interval;
        echo 'Num Of Loops: '. round($numOfLoops).'<br/>';
// For loop will control the results sets divided by 4 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfLoops; $i++) {
        // To add the offset after the first set
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $limitValues =  $offset. ", " . $interval . " ";
        } else {
            $limitValues = $interval;
        }
        $sqlquery = $q . "  LIMIT " . $limitValues;
        $avg = 0;
        $total = 0;
        //Total Found Use To Divide by
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //echo 'Total Found: '.$num_rows;
        foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery) as $results) {
            // Do Something
            $total += $results['score'];
            $avg = $total / $interval;
            print_r($results['purdate'].' <-> ');
 //see [edit2] need only the first date in assoc array?? $results['purdate'][0] doesn't work
        }
        echo $avg . '<br/>';
        $offset += $interval;
    } 
}
```

[edit1]
i add some code to get the startDate for each interval also some code for start to handle the rest value

```
function getConsecutiveInterval($interval) {
    //$interval Num Of Consecutive Days
    global $conn;
    $offset = '';
    // Query is the same and at the end of it you include LIMIT to be controlled by the loop.
        $q = "SELECT a.purdate, b.score, a.status FROM records a INNER JOIN scores2 b ON a.purdate = b.date AND a.personid = b.personid WHERE a.personid = 133 AND a.status IN('P','T') ORDER BY purdate ASC, score DESC ";

    //Total Found Use To Divide by
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo 'Total Found: '.$num_rows.'<br/>';
        $numOfLoops = floor($num_rows/$interval);
        echo 'Num Of Loops: '. $numOfLoops.'<br/>';
        $rest = $num_rows - ($interval*$numOfLoops);
        echo 'Rest: '.$rest.'<br/>'; 
        $arrFound = [];
// For loop will control the results sets divided by 4 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfLoops; $i++) {
        // To add the offset after the first set
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $limitValues =  $offset. ", " . $interval . " ";
        } else {
            $limitValues = $interval;
        }
        $sqlquery = $q . "  LIMIT " . $limitValues;
        $avg = 0;
        $total = 0;
        //Total Found Use To Divide by
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //echo 'Total Found: '.$num_rows;
        $j = 0;

        foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery) as $results) {
            if ($j == 0) {
                 echo $results['purdate'];
                 $arrFound[$i]['date'] = $results['purdate'];
            }
            // Do Something
            $total += $results['score'];
            $avg = $total / $interval;

            $j++;
        }
        $arrFound[$i]['avg'] = $avg;
        echo $avg . '<br/>';
        $offset += $interval;
    } 
    print_r($arrFound);
}
```

[edit2]
In the end I also need the start purdate of each interval to be returned in the array as well.

[edit3]

For another table I need something similar but now I need to output also per code. The query looks like this :

```
$q = "SELECT date, code
      FROM Records2 
      WHERE studentid = 131
      AND date >= '2017-02-10' AND date <= '2017-06-13'
      AND code IN ('P','T','L','U') 
      ORDER BY date ASC;";
```

and with the help of astrangeloop I like this to output per code as well. This is to plot a chart where x-axis will be the start date and y-axis will plot the number of P, T, L or U. (well mostly P and T)

example chart would be:
[image: stacked graph example]

```
  $intervals = array();
    foreach (array_chunk($records, $interval_size) as 
    $interval_records) {
        $first_record = reset($interval_records);
        $interval = array(
            'start' => $first_record['date'],
            'codes' => array_column($interval_records, 'code'),
            /*Is It Possible to Order and/or Calculate with the 
        code values? Like another array*/,
        );
        $intervals[] = $interval;
    }
    return $intervals;
```

At the moment this returns:

```
[5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-03-23
            [codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => P
                    [1] => P
                    [2] => P
                    [3] => P
                    [4] => P
                )

            [count] => 5
        )
```

And I like the js output which looks likes this:

```
['start', #num_of_codes_P, #num_of_codes_T, #num_of_codes_L, #num_of_codes_U,'count'],
['start', #num_of_codes_P, #num_of_codes_T, #num_of_codes_L, #num_of_codes_U,'count'],
```

For future reference I think I found a workable solution (not using array_count_values because of Notice error) and this is how I get the codes:

```
$records = getRecordsWithIntervals($records, 5);
foreach ($records as $record) {
   echo count(array_keys($record['codes'], 'P')).', '.count(array_keys($record['codes'], 'U')).'<br/>';
}
```

[edit4] I should ask this in a seperate question, but how do I add the ability to set the interval_size to weekly, monthly or customize quarters (custom beginDate-endDate = divide a educational year in 4 parts or more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a query to select all the scores from the database at once, one possible approach might be to do this in php rather than by querying the database again for each interval. You can fetch everything from the database in one go, then use php's `array_chunk()` function to slice an array into the intervals you're interested in and calcluate averages etc. from there:

```
function getRecords()
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "
        SELECT a.purdate
             , b.score
             , a.status
          FROM records a 
          JOIN scores2 b 
            ON a.purdate = b.date 
           AND a.personid = b.personid 
         WHERE a.personid = 133 
           AND a.status IN('P','T') 
         ORDER 
            BY purdate ASC
             , score DESC
             ;
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $records = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $records;
}

function getIntervalsWithAverageScores(array $records, $interval_size)
{
    $intervals = array();
    foreach (array_chunk($records, $interval_size) as $interval_records) {
        $first_record = reset($interval_records);
        $interval = array(
            'start' => $first_record['purdate'],
            'scores' => array_column($interval_records, 'score'),
            'count' => count($interval_records),
            'average' => array_sum(array_column($interval_records, 'score')) / count($interval_records),
        );
        $intervals[] = $interval;
    }
    return $intervals;
}
```

Using these functions as follows:

```
$records = getRecords();
var_dump(getIntervalsWithAverageScores($records, 4));
var_dump(getIntervalsWithAverageScores($records, 3));
```

Will give output like this (tested in php 5.6):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2015-06-11"
    ["scores"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["count"]=>
    int(4)
    ["average"]=>
    float(2.75)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2016-01-02"
    ["scores"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["count"]=>
    int(4)
    ["average"]=>
    float(3.5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2016-10-13"
    ["scores"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "4"
    }
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["average"]=>
    float(3.5)
  }
}
// second internal array omitted ...
```

You can see the last entry in the array has a count of 2 and only 2 scores, rather than 4.

As an aside, if you will be using user input instead of hard-coded values in future, please look in to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to protect yourself from sql injection.

Comment: tx for your suggestion and is a clearer way of getting the output I already have. But I don't think my question is clear: I like to return the rest values as well but dealing with the fact that it is an incomplete interval. So in case of an interval of 4, it would be 2015-06-11, 2015-12-12, 2016-10-13 (but this is for the rest value). So in case of interval 3 I like the output to show the last average is based on 1 value and in case of interval 4 the last average is based on 2 values. I have put an edit1 some code to start to handle the rest value logic, hope you can help.

Comment: but I need to reread your answer a couple of times as it might be easier way to get the first purdate also back. Then I should somehow make array scores an associative array with the first purdate of an interval, right?? or can i use array_column for this one as well?

Comment: I've edited my answer to capture extra information about each interval.

Comment: btw: for protection I am using `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $personid);
    $stmt->execute();`

Comment: edit3 I think I solved that one by using `count(array_keys...`

Comment: Do you know a starting point, if I want to add the ability to set the interval_size to weekly, monthly or customize quarters (beginDate-endDate, mostly divide a educational year in 4 parts)

Comment: I was going to suggest that you should open another question for this, but I see you've already done it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658979/how-can-i-loop-through-an-array-of-dates-and-group-by-week-month-or-custom-quar    - Good luck!

Comment: can I pick your brain again? I think have asked the wrong original question. Here's my updated question which I hope is a bit clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703814/php-records-by-interval-of-x-days-and-taking-into-account-all-dates-within-the-d

Comment: I am bit stuck with the fact that the array_chunk on my $records doesn't recognize the different code values. As the interval should stop after - for a 5 day- 5 days with code P or L, but inbetween the start of an interval and the end of the interval there can be other values which I need to take into account.