# PHP records by interval of x-days and taking into account all dates within the date range?

Tags: php, mysql, date

[UPDATED with more logic]

Hope I have made my question a bit clearer, by adding the table, sqlfidddle and the php functions I am using now.

This is simple represent of a table I am working with:

```
+-------------+--------+------------+----------+
| person      | status | purdate    | personid |
+-------------+--------+------------+----------+
| person_name | A      | 2016-06-03 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-06-06 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-06-07 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-06-12 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-06-22 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-06-22 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-06-24 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-07-01 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-07-02 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-07-03 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-07-11 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-08-05 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-08-10 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-08-12 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-08-13 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-08-18 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-08-19 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-08-20 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-08-25 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-08-26 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-09-12 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-09-14 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-09-17 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-09-27 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-09-30 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-10-09 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-10-17 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-10-23 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-10-26 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-10-27 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-10-29 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-11-01 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-11-03 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-11-05 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-11-06 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-11-10 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-11-16 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-11-22 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-11-22 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-11-29 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-03 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-12-08 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-09 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-10 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-14 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-12-16 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2016-12-16 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-12-17 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2016-12-23 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-12-23 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-12-23 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-24 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2016-12-26 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2016-12-27 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-30 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2016-12-31 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-01-01 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-01-01 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-01-03 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-01-08 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-01-09 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-01-10 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-01-12 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-01-16 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-01-21 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-01-21 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-01-22 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-01-25 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-01-31 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-02-02 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-02-05 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-02-07 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-02-10 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-02-18 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-02-18 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-02-19 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-02-26 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-03-08 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-03-17 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-03-18 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-03-18 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-03-23 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-03-23 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-03-24 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-03-27 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-03-28 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-03-30 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-03-31 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-04-05 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-04-07 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-04-10 |      133 |
| person_name | T      | 2017-04-10 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-04-11 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-04-19 |      133 |
| person_name | A      | 2017-04-22 |      133 |
| person_name | P      | 2017-04-24 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-04-26 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-04-28 |      133 |
| person_name | U      | 2017-05-06 |      133 |
| person_name | L      | 2017-05-08 |      133 |
+-------------+--------+------------+----------+
```

Here's a simple sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4456e/3

A/ Now I need the records by interval of x-days where Status = P Or L. So I need a counter which stops where there are 30x code P or L found (skipping T, U, A and empty dates)

I need to take into account all dates within the date range also empty once. This will also include dates for which there is no input(=no code), for these dates I can set the code to NULL (they represent mostly weekends and holidays).

At the moment I am testing with to following php function (tx astrangeloop), which only make interval chunks without the status logic (= P or L)

```
function getRecordsWithIntervalsFault(array $records, $interval_size)
{
    $intervals = array();
    foreach (array_chunk($records, $interval_size) as $interval_records) {
        $first_record = reset($interval_records);
        $last_record = end($interval_records);
        $total = count($records);
        $interval = array(
            'start' => $first_record['purdate'],
            'end'   => $last_record['purdate'],
            'codes' => array_column($interval_records, 'status'),
            'count' => count($interval_records),
            'periodLength' => dateRangeInDays($first_record['purdate'], $last_record['purdate']),
            'total' => $total,
        );
        $intervals[] = $interval;
    }
    return $intervals;
}
$recordsForJs = getRecordsWithIntervalsFault($records, 30);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($recordsForJs);
echo '</pre>';
```

With the following helper function to get the range between begin - end interval in days:

```
function dateRangeInDays($start, $end) {
$beginDate =strtotime($start); // or your date as well
$endDate = strtotime($end);
$datediff = $endDate - $beginDate;

return round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

And to get the records from the table I use this simple function

```
$records = getRecords(133);
function getRecords($personid)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "
    SELECT a.purdate
         , a.status
      FROM recordsA a
     WHERE a.personid = ?
     ORDER 
        BY purdate ASC;
    ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $personid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $records = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $records;
}
```

In the end i like to calculate average per interval like sum(instance of P and L)/ sum(instance of 'P','L','T','U','A') within the interval.

And I need the sum(instance of P and L) for further calculations

B/ [Edit] Will ask a new question to combine A with looking up incidentDate in tableB

[EDIT]
I am testing with this logic

```
function getIntervalsWithAverageScoresTEST(array $records, $interval_size) {
    $intervals = array();

    foreach ($records as $interval_records) {
       $count = 0;
       if($interval_records['status'] == 'P' || $interval_records['status'] =='L'){
        if($count < $interval_size){
            $first_record = reset($interval_records);
            $last_record = end($interval_records);
            $interval = array(
                'startDate' => $interval_records['purdate'],
                'endDate' => $interval_records['purdate'],
                'statuses' => array_column($interval_records, 'status'),
                'count' => count($interval_records),
            );
            $intervals[] = $interval;
            $count++;
        }
        }
    }
    return $intervals;

}
```

Comment: Incidentally, neither person nor date are reserved keywords, but of the two, date seems a more plausible candidate for reservation than person! So one wonders on the backtick logic.

Comment: @strawberry Sorry this is merely a part of the table.

Comment: Can you give us an example (desired) output, because at the moment it is quite unclear what you are asking. And also a sample of the resultset from the query?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have updated/edited my question a bit

Comment: Use the `@` symbol before specific usernames to send them a message like: @strawberry

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? And as per previous, what would the desired result look like?